# Facebook extend sso access token error

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using facebook SDK 3.0.1 for android.
I see at Facebook developers -> Insights -> Developer -> Activity & Errors 
some erros.
I have an error that happens to 100% of my users : auth.extendssoaccesstoken (error code  10 : Application does not have permission for this action).
I've read that this problems may happens after removing the deprecated permission offline_access.
What could that be?
and how can I solve that problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your Application is in Sandbox Mode ? The Sandbox Mode only allows the developer to access the application. You can change this from your App Settings on Facebook.